Is it possible to create azure subscription quota alerts using terraform azurerm provider?
I see that azurerm provider has azurerm_monitor_metric_alert but does not appear to support azure quota alerts.  Various AI think I can use azurerm_monitor_metric_alert with a scope like `/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/${location}/providers/Microsoft.Quota/quotas/standardDPLDSv5Family"
but this doesn't seem to be the case.  It seems to be impossible to manage subscription quota alerts via terraform.  Is this right?
